# HTML5 - audio stream

Tags: html, audio, stream

when I run my application audio stream in browser, no problem but when I run it in BB web/widget it is not appear in my BB simulator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what BB means, but it probably does not have HTML5 support, yet. You might want to consider using [jPlayer](http://www.jplayer.org/), it will automatically detect the presence of HTML5, if HTML5 doesn't exist, it will present the audio using flash.

Comment: thanks for your respond.. jplayer is a jquery..I haven't try this before. Is it support my blackberry simulator and real device?

Comment: when i try, it work at my browser but it can't work at my blackberry simulator storm2 9550 (5.0.0.469)?

Comment: The simulator may or may not work depending on how sophisticated the simulator is implemented, but jPlayer should indeed work in your blackberry because blackberry has flash support: http://blog.weswareonline.com/2010/05/blackberry-embracing-adobes-flash-apple.html

Comment: I'ts still not working dude..any idea or suggestion? I have try in 3 way, 1st, code html5 standard, 2nd used jplayer script and 3rd used kalkuta script. this 3 way work in browser, when i run it in BB simulator, its not working..